# How to access specific product id on other pages/posts?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I have the following code, which is adding some HTML to the product page, according to the product and its fields, attributes, etc.

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_meta_start', 'addHtmlToProductPage');

function addHtmlToProductPage(){
    global $product; 

    $manufacture_url = get_field( "manufacture_url" );
    $manufacture_logo = get_field( "manufacture_logo" );
    
    echo 'some html' + $manufacture_url + $manufacture_logo + 'some html'

}
```

I want to add it to other posts as well. How do I access specific products id on other pages/posts?

I assume it's got something related to 'global $product'

Comment: If it's not on a product page then you have to find a way to tell that post/page which product it is you're referencing, and if you're already doing that association then you have the ID.  The global should only work on a page where the product ID is specified in some other manner.  What I mean is, how do you decided which product is being displayed on a post/page?

Comment: @TonyDjukic, i know the product/post id. My PHP isn't very good, so how do i set `$product` to the right product?

Comment: That would very much depend on use case and what you're trying to do.  If it's a page, how are you determining which product is being displayed on that page?  Is there an automated process, are you manually assigning it in the backend, is it just one product on all pages regardless of their content/context?

Comment: @Tony, i can hard code it. It's not a automatic process for all products, it's just a few products. I need the code as the data of the product changes (price, availability etc.)

Comment: @TonyDjukic,  i can hard code it. It's not an automatic process for all products, it's just a few products at a time. I need the code as the data of the product changes (price, availability etc.)

Comment: This is why the `$product` global isn't helping.  Instead just assign the id of the product you want: `$product_id = 92;`  Then use `$manufacture_url = get_field( "manufacture_url", $product_id, true );`

Want me to write the whole thing out in an answer for you?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks the Tony Djukic coment, here is a working code example:

```
<?PHP
    $product_id = 92; /*hard code the product id */
    $manufacture_url = get_field( "manufacture_url", $product_id, true );
    
    echo 'some html' + $manufacture_url + 'some html'
?>
```

The product ID can be found in the product URL on editing mode.

I used xyz PHP plugin the create shortcode and manually forward the product id variable in the shortcode itself.  So I can maintain 1 short code for all posts.